# Derivative of a map $f:\mathbb R \to \ell^2 $ to a separable Hilbert space vs derivative of each component of the Hilbert basis.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces

${\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}}$ Let $\ell^2 $ be the Hilbert space of square summable sequences of real numbers.

Consider a map $f: \R \to \ell^2$,  that has components $f_n:\R\to \R$, i.e. $f(t)=\{f_n(t)\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ so that $\sum_n(f_n(t))^2<+\infty$.

**Motivation**

If the derivative  $\frac d {dt}f(t)$ exists, then it is given by $\{\partial_tf_n(t)\}_n\in \ell^2$ componentwise.
However the existence of the derivatives $\{\partial_tf_n(t)\}_n\in \ell^2$ does not imply the existence of $\frac d {dt}f(t)$, because we need the remainder
$$ R_n(t,h) = f_n(t+h) - f_n(t) - \partial_t f_n(t)h $$
to be $o(|h|)$ for $h\to 0$ *uniformely* in $n$.

I would like to know if adding a Sobolev-type assumption we obtain existence of the derivative, precisely:

**Question:**

> Let $f$ as above, and suppose that the componentwise derivativee  $\{\partial^{(k)}_t f_n\}_n \in \ell^2$ and the $\partial^{(k)}_t f_n$ are continuous for $k\leq 2$. Moreover assume that
> $$\int_\R \sum_n n^2|\partial_t^{(k)}f_n(t)|^2 dt <\infty$$
> Does this  imply that the derivative $\frac {d}{dt}f(t) \in \ell^2$ exists for all $t$? (and thus coincide with $\{\partial_t f_n\}_n$).